# Traduzione di "commit" in informatica (es. "git commit")

Tags: translation, single-words, english-comparison

Esiste una traduzione italiana del termine tecnico "commit" (nome o verbo) usato nel gergo di [Git](https://git-scm.com/)?

Più generalmente, esiste un dizionario online di termini informatici correnti? Sono nato in Italia ma ho fatto la maggior parte della mia carriera informatica negli USA e mi rendo conto che non so tradurre molte frasi che uso in inglese ogni giorno.

Comment: Belle domande, di cui non conosco le risposte. Temo però che visto che le innovazioni tecnologiche vengono da decenni da paesi anglofoni, nell'informatica italiana si faccia uso massiccio di anglismi non adattati, quindi credo che la tua situazione sia condivisa da molte persone del settore che lavorano in Italia. Nello specifico, Microsoft usa l'anglismo "commit" anche in italiano: https://docs.microsoft.com/it-it/learn/modules/introduction-to-github/, https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/it/vs/github/ .

Comment: Grazie Andrea. In assenza di contro-esempi penso che si possa seguire l'esempio della Microsoft, nonostante quell'azienda tenda a usare i propri standard e termini senza troppo guardare alla comunità.... (spesso si tende anche a confondere Git con Github)

Comment: In generale, come già detto, si tende a non tradurre. Infatti, se imposti una IDE come Studio Code in italiano, i comandi non vengono tradotti, ma saranno: "esegui push", "esegui pull" e "esgui commit".

Poi nel gergo informatico si tende spesso ad italianizzare le parole che diventano "pushare", "committare" etc..

Answer (score 3):

Essendo l'inglese la lingua "ufficiale" della programmazione, molti termini tecnici derivano dalla lingua comune, ma per loro specificità non sempre possono essere tradotti come il termine originale.

In contesto informatico, "commit" implica genericamente il rendere effettive delle modifiche: per esempio, in seguito alla query di un database in cui si aggiungono o modificano dei campi.

"Commit" ha diversi significati in inglese, tra quelli [elencati dall'Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/commit) questi sono quelli semanticamente più affini all'utilizzo informatico:

- **commit something to memory**: to learn something well enough to remember it exactly

  *She committed the instructions to memory.*
- **commit something to paper/writing**: to write something down - *from Latin committere ‘join, entrust’ (in medieval Latin ‘put into custody’), from com- ‘with’ + mittere ‘put or send’*

Chiaramente, "commettere" non è la traduzione giusta, per via del significato odierno; in certi contesti linguistici si può usare "applicare" (e le sue varianti o sinonimi), ma è solitamente utilizzato solo da un punto di vista di *documentazione* o di dialogo con l'utente.

Se ci si riferisce al termine tecnico in sé (il comando, o l'oggetto), il termine diventa più specifico: se è vero che stai rendendo effettive le modifiche del repository, il termine si riferisce allo stesso momento anche al nome del comando.

In tal caso, bisogna distinguere il destinatario del testo ed il contesto di utilizzo. Se la parola è usata in "senso discorsivo", si può usare un termine di simile significato in italiano, se il riferimento è al comando specifico, si preferisce l'originale, a meno che non esista già una convenzione diffusa.

Ricordiamoci inoltre che alcuni termini tecnici in inglese (come "bug" o "log"), sebbene abbiano una possibile traduzione "ovvia", non sono praticamente mai tradotti in nessuna lingua (sorvoliamo sul francese ;-) ), e che in quella lingua è anche frequente rendere sostantivi (neologismi compresi) dei verbi.
"Commit" quindi può indicare:

- l'azione: "Commit changes to the repository" si può tradurre con "Applica i cambiamenti al repository";
- il suo risultato: "Show the last commit" sarà molto probabilmente "Mostra l'ultimo commit";
- la sua "invocazione": "Execute `commit`";

L'ultimo significato è ovviamente un caso di non traducibilità, ma esistono situazioni di comandi tradotti (vedi Excel).

In linea di massima, quindi, "commit" resta tale e quale nel contesto dei repository, specialmente quando il legame con il comando è specifico del contesto del discorso.

Comment: Grazie per la risposta e per l'accenno al contesto dei database (altro anglismo diffuso, nonostante si possa tradurre come "banche dati"!). Pare quindi che il termine inglese sia quello più comunemente usato. La traduzione italiana più giusta sembrerebbe "impegno", che si usa anche in contesto legale e quindi è più vicino al concetto, ma il termine non tradotto va benissimo se è quello in uso corrente.

Comment: Breve nota: i casi in cui "commit" si traduce "commettere" è con "crimine", "omicidio" o "suicidio": gli ultimi due sono senza dubbio i tipi di '"impegno" più irrevocabile possibile.

Comment: @user3758232 In origine avevo volutamente scritto "banche dati" proprio per consistenza del contesto, ma poi rileggendo la preview ho fatto un po' di editing e s'è perso nella queue degli undo ;-) Davvero il senso in inglese è legato al significato di commit/impegno? Onestamente ho pensato alle voci che ho elencato sopra, anche se il significato semantico è ambiguo e comunque correlato (simile al concetto "save" per la scrittura su memoria, esattamente come "commit to paper/memory"). Il commettere del tuo secondo commento è legato al "fare" o "compiere": la radice latina è la stessa, ma ne è->

Comment: -> mutato il significato ed ha ormai ha da secoli un'accezione genericamente negativa. Comunque, sì, la parola originale è la norma, come ormai quasi tutti i termini tecnici: l'integrazione di termini tecnologici inglesi è ormai uno... ehm... standard ;-) le traduzioni erano ben più frequenti in passato, anche perché spesso i termini erano più semplici, generici, meno specifici e più facilmente localizzabili. Occhio che talvolta si coniugano verbi ("linkare"), soprattutto in certi ambienti. Tendenzialmente è meglio evitarli, anche perché spesso danno risultati quasi sempre orripilanti.

Comment: Ho trovato "impegno" in contesti politici e legali in una serie di vocabolari online prima di rivolgermi a questo forum. Sono d'accordo sulla predominanza anglosassone dei termini informatici, anche se in qualche caso si può fare un piccolo sforzo e usare un termine italiano, se a portata di mano. O evitare terribili traduzioni (ad es. l'ormai stabilito "salvare" per "save") e coniugazioni (mi sono assuefatto a "cliccare", ma "linkare" mi fa ancora venire la pelle d'oca, e "googlare"... lasciamo perdere). In ogni caso, conversazione interessantissima. Grazie delle iformazioni.

Comment: Ok, tieni conto che nel contesto politico e legale, l'accezione è derivata dal significato simile a "entrust": impegnarsi [con] qualcuno/qualcosa, come in "commitment". La radice latina (parafrasabile nell'italiano "con" e "mettere") ha un significato semantico simile, e mi viene in mente una forma italiana comune che ha la stessa accezione: "mettere per iscritto" (che indica, appunto, un impegno). Sarebbe interessante trovare un informatico madrelingua e studioso dell'inglese per chiedere il significato semantico di "commit". Magari si potrebbe porre una domanda su english.stackexchange.

Comment: In realtà, esistono già alcune domande rilevanti, facendo una semplice [ricerca](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=commit), tipo [questa](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/266657), che fa riferimento anche all'uso in quanto sostantivo. Andando a intuito, resto dell'idea che il senso informatico sia comunque quello scritto nella mia risposta ("commit to paper"), è sì un "impegno", ma non tanto nella forma di "obbligo" bensì di "mantenimento" ("applica", "salva", "memorizza", etc.). Comunque, sì, conversazione interessante, grazie a te per lo spunto di riflessione :-)

Answer (score 1):

Alcune guide usano il verbo **registrare**, per esempio [questa](https://yunwuxin1.gitbooks.io/git/content/it/a08ec039d4174e2f33147a88c2e4db76/04f252f2f8458d81f0cf411c36729c23.html).

Comunque è una forte minoranza e l'uso prevalente è di tenere la parola inglese così com'è, come spesso succede con i termini informatici. Tradurla potrebbe essere addirittura dannoso per la memoria, visto che poi l'utente deve comunque avere in testa la parola inglese `commit` per scriverla all'interno dei comandi.

Una conversazione media tra due informatici probabilmente farebbe venire un colpo apoplettico a un purista dell'italiano, ma è così che va il mondo. :)

Comment: Grazie del documento, ha diversi termini interessanti (come "parcheggiare" per "stash"). "Registrare" sembra piuttosto generico però, e più in fondo noto che l'autore usa il sostantivo inglese "commit", probabilmente perché non c'è un sostantivo convincente che corrisponde direttamente a "registrare". A quel punto, direi "commit all the way"...

Comment: Riguardo al tuo commento sul memorizzare i termini inglesi per la programmazione e le traduzioni italiane (dove opportuno) per la conversazione, non lo ritengo una cosa negativa. Anzi, penso sia un buon esercizio mentale per un programmatore che cambia linguaggio quando parla ad una persona (italiana), ed evita il tipo di conversazione di cui parli (un problema non solo informatico: a sentire certi imprenditorucci che infarciscono le conversazioni di anglismi viene un colpo apoplettico anche a me, che non sono sicuramente un purista).